# How to get the previous quarters data in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a Table.

Table1

```
Id  Sid Date    Value
3   25  31-Oct-16   12
3   25  30-Nov-16   13
3   25  31-Dec-16   14
3   25  31-Jan-17   15
3   25  28-Feb-17   16
3   25  31-Mar-17   17
3   25  30-Apr-17   18
3   25  31-May-17   19
3   25  30-Jun-17   20
3   25  31-Jul-17   21
3   25  31-Aug-17   22
3   25  30-Sep-17   23
3   25  31-Oct-17   24
3   25  30-Nov-17   25
3   25  31-Dec-17   26
3   25  31-Jan-18   27
3   25  28-Feb-18   28
3   25  31-Mar-18   29
3   25  30-Apr-18   30
3   25  31-May-18   31
3   25  30-Jun-18   32
```

I am trying to get the previous 7 quarters data as below:

```
Id  Sid Date    Value
3   25  31-Dec-16   14
3   25  31-Mar-17   17
3   25  30-Jun-17   20
3   25  30-Sep-17   23
3   25  31-Dec-17   26
3   25  31-Mar-18   29
3   25  30-Jun-18   32
```

I am trying to use **DATEADD** and **DATEDIFF** function however not getting the expected results. below is the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Date BETWEEN DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) -7, 0) AND GETDATE()
```

any hints or idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate the *not getting the expected results* part? How different the query results compared to the expected result?

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server? This is important to know and you should always tag your question accordingly...

Comment: Btw: You should introduce a date-numbers-table to your database. This is very helpful in many situations and would make this super easy...

Answer (score 0):

This here will do the trick - Properbly not the most elegant way, but it should work.

```
      declare @table table (Id int,  Sid int, date Date ,value int)

insert into @table

values
(3  ,25  ,'31-Oct-16',   12),
(3  ,25  ,'30-Nov-16',   13),
(3  ,25  ,'31-Dec-16',   14),
(3  ,25  ,'31-Jan-17',   15),
(3  ,25  ,'28-Feb-17',   16),
(3  ,25  ,'31-Mar-17',   17),
(3  ,25  ,'30-Apr-17',   18),
(3  ,25  ,'31-May-17',   19),
(3  ,25  ,'30-Jun-17',   20),
(3  ,25  ,'31-Jul-17',   21),
(3  ,25  ,'31-Aug-17',   22),
(3  ,25  ,'30-Sep-17',   23),
(3  ,25  ,'31-Oct-17',   24),
(3  ,25  ,'30-Nov-17',   25),
(3  ,25  ,'31-Dec-17',   26),
(3  ,25  ,'31-Jan-18',   27),
(3  ,25  ,'28-Feb-18',   28),
(3  ,25  ,'31-Mar-18',   29),
(3  ,25  ,'30-Apr-18',   30),
(3  ,25  ,'31-May-18',   31),
(3  ,25  ,'30-Jun-18',   32)

select id,sid,date,value from (
select *    
,row_number() over(partition by id order by date desc) as RankNo


 from @table
where date = DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, date) + 1, 0)) 
)x where  RankNo <=7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-- @a set first day month
DECLARE @a date =  DATEADD(day,1,DATEADD(month,-1,EOMONTH(GETDATE())))

SELECT @a, DATEADD(qq, -7,  @a) 
--2018-07-01 2016-10-01
Date BETWEEN DATEADD(qq, -7,  @a)  AND @a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 where datepart(mm,date) in (3,6,9,12)
```

Comment: I think 1 of the simplest approach for a bit complex problem. If the user do not have any other constraint. Full marks.

Comment: This wont work if he has serveral years. It says previous 7.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really know what you need and you did not tell us the version you are using.

This code will compute some relevant values from different inputs using functions available in almost all versions.

Higher versions allow for `EOMONTH`, `DATEFROMPARTS`, `FORMAT` ...
[Read this and follow the links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

And - as told in a comment - you should introduce a *date and numbers* table.

Just to give an idea:

```
DECLARE @tblDates TABLE(dt DATE);
INSERT INTO @tblDates VALUES(GETDATE()),({d'2018-01-01'})
                                       ,({d'2018-03-31'})
                                       ,({d'2018-04-30'})
                                       ,({d'2018-05-17'})
                                       ,({d'2018-11-30'})
                                       ,({d'2018-12-31'});
select *
FROM @tblDates dts
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CAST(Year(dt) AS CHAR(4)) + '-' + REPLACE(STR(MONTH(dt),2),' ','0') + '-01',126)) A(FirstOfMonth)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,(-1)*(MONTH(A.FirstOfMonth)-1)%3,A.FirstOfMonth)) B(FirstOfQuarter)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT DATEADD(QQ,-7,B.FirstOfQuarter)) C(SevenQuartersBack);
```

The result:

```
dt          FoM         FoQ         SevenQuartersBack
2018-07-24  2018-07-01  2018-07-01  2016-10-01
2018-01-01  2018-01-01  2018-01-01  2016-04-01
2018-03-31  2018-03-01  2018-01-01  2016-04-01
2018-04-30  2018-04-01  2018-04-01  2016-07-01
2018-05-17  2018-05-01  2018-04-01  2016-07-01
2018-11-30  2018-11-01  2018-10-01  2017-01-01
2018-12-31  2018-12-01  2018-10-01  2017-01-01
```